# Compare multiple lists with same structure for the one with smaller integers at lowest positions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, compare, comparison

I have multiple lists (**arbitrary number of lists, not pre-set**) of the type [65, 34, 13, 6] and all elements have diminishing sizes from index [0] to length (e.g. 65 > 34 > 13 > 6). I want to compare all of them and keep the one that has the smallest integers, ranked by highest index. For example:

Input:

```
[165, 54, 33, 6]
[165, 34, 24, 6]
[65, 23, 13, 6]
[65, 55, 5, 6]
```

Should output:

```
[65, 55, 5, 6]
```

since the `5` is the smallest integer compared to `13, 24 and 33` at the highest position that doesn't have equal values. In the example above, the all lists have equal value at highest index (length-1 slot) so we need to compare the [length-2] slot. There, the smallest of values is `5`, so the algorithm stops here and returns the last list with `5` at [length-2] index.

If all elements in `[-1] and [-2]` where equal, check should utilize the next highest index.

The answer must not combine different values from multiple lists, it must choose one of the existing lists with the lowest value at the highest position.

Is there a fast way to execute such a comparison?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your lists are decreasing, you can use:

```
idx, val = [(i, min(vals)) for i, vals in enumerate(zip(*lsts)) if len(set(vals))>1][-1]
output = [l for l in lsts if l[idx]==val][0]
```

###### Examples:

```
lsts = [[165, 54, 33, 6], 
        [165, 34, 24, 6], 
        [65, 23, 13, 6], 
        [65, 55, 5, 6]]

idx, val = [(i, min(vals)) for i, vals in enumerate(zip(*lsts)) if len(set(vals))>1][-1]
>>> [l for l in lsts if l[idx]==val][0]
[65, 55, 5, 6]

lsts = [[165, 54, 24, 6], 
        [165, 34, 24, 6], 
        [65, 23, 24, 6], 
        [65, 55, 24, 6]]

idx, val = [(i, min(vals)) for i, vals in enumerate(zip(*lsts)) if len(set(vals))>1][-1]
>>> [l for l in lsts if l[idx]==val][0]
[65, 23, 24, 6]
```

Comment: This is almost correct, can you please edit your answer to return the entire list that is relevant to each output? e.g. instead of 23, it should return its list, i.e. [65, 23, 24, 6]

Comment: It is not clear to me how we can return the entire list and not simply the value of the element. Also, this does not work for arbitrary number of lists, for example in a list of lists how can I assign variables to min()?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the `zip` function to group all elements by index then use the `min` function on it to get the minimum at each position :

```py
l1 = [165, 54, 33, 6]
l2 = [165, 34, 24, 6]
l3 = [65, 23, 13, 6]
l4 = [65, 55, 5, 6]

output = [min(elements) for elements in zip(l1, l2, l3, l4)]
```

Comment: This produces [65, 23, 5, 6] which is not the correct answer. Your answer combines the lowest ranks, it does not choose the list with the lowest value at the highest position

Answer (score 0):

Another version:

```py
lsts = [[165, 54, 33, 6], [165, 34, 24, 6], [65, 23, 13, 6], [65, 55, 5, 6]]

out = next(
    lsts[min(enumerate(t), key=lambda k: k[1])[0]]
    for t in zip(*map(reversed, lsts))
    if len(set(t)) > 1
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[65, 55, 5, 6]
```